# how to run a task from outside the shell

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

hi I want to access a task outside the shell and execute it from my app/controller. How can I do that

```
<?php
 class SeaShell extends Shell { // found in /vendors/shells/sea.php  
     var $tasks = array('Sound'); //found in /vendors/shells/tasks/sound.php 
     function main() {      
                  $this->Sound->execute();   
     }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you put your logic in a Model or Component. This way it is accessible from both shells and controllers.

Comment: well I was hoping there was app::import() something?

Comment: sure, you can app::import everything! but as minaz said, it might not be the most elegant way of doing things